# How can I allow a client to specify the fields they want returned from my api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I'd like to mimic some popular APIs and one of the things that I see a lot is that the client query a web api and specify which fields to return. So for instance, looking up a user's details could have a ton of info, or just basic info. Rather than creating separate endpoints for all the different levels of detail, I'd like to just be able to allow the client to request as much information as they need. This is a private api.

So on the server, I'd like to just use a users complete data (eagerly loaded or lazy loaded; it hasn't been determined yet), but then once I have that object, I'd like to use the fields specified in the client's request to build the response object.

Is there a library for this? Or any popular techniques or articles would be helpful. TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an involved process but basically you want to just loop the objects returned if properties are passed in and return a dictionary of those properties. I created an extension method for doing it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace YourNamespace.Extensions
{
    public enum PropertyFormat
    {
        AsIs,
        PascalCase,
        CamelCase
    }

    public static class DataShapingExtensions
    {
        public static object ToDataShape<ObjectIn>(this ObjectIn objectToShape, string fields, PropertyFormat propertyFormat = PropertyFormat.AsIs) where ObjectIn : class
        {
            var listOfFields = new List<string>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fields))
            {
                listOfFields = fields.ToLower().Split(',').ToList();
            }

            if (listOfFields.Any())
            {
                var objectToReturn = new JObject();

                //====
                var enumerable = objectToShape as IEnumerable;

                if (enumerable != null)
                {
                    var listOfObjects = new List<JObject>();

                    foreach (var item in enumerable)
                    {
                        var objectToReturn2 = new JObject();

                        listOfFields.ForEach(field =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var prop = item.GetType()
                                    .GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                                var fieldName = prop.Name;
                                var fieldValue = prop.GetValue(item, null);

                                fieldName = GetName(fieldName, propertyFormat);
                                objectToReturn2.Add(new JProperty(fieldName, fieldValue));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { }
                        });

                        listOfObjects.Add(objectToReturn2);
                    }

                    return listOfObjects.ConvertAll(o => o);
                }
                //====

                listOfFields.ForEach(field =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var prop = objectToShape.GetType()
                            .GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                        var fieldName = prop.Name;
                        var fieldValue = prop.GetValue(objectToShape, null);

                        fieldName = GetName(fieldName, propertyFormat);
                        objectToReturn.Add(new JProperty(fieldName, fieldValue));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                });

                return objectToReturn;
            }

            return objectToShape;
        }

        private static string GetName(string field, PropertyFormat propertyFormat)
        {
            switch (propertyFormat)
            {
                case PropertyFormat.AsIs: return field;
                case PropertyFormat.PascalCase: return field.ToPascalCase();
                case PropertyFormat.CamelCase: return field.ToCamelCase();
                default: return field;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it you would check for passed in fields on the route.

```
[HttpGet, Route("/api/yourRoute")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetListOfYourObjects(string fields = null)
{
    try
    {
        var yourObject = await repo.GetYourListFromRepo();

        if (fields.HasValue())
        {
           return Ok(yourObject.ToDataShape(fields, PropertyFormat.CamelCase));
        }

        return Ok(yourObject);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

Then to shape the data returned when you call the route say from ajax you would pass in the fields you want.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/api/yourRoute?fields=field1,field2"
})
```

Which would return you an object with just those fields.

```
{
  field1: "",
  field2: ""
}
```